# white mold on underside of shed plywood

Tags: mold

[image]My new shed i built last year has what appears to be a white mold on the underside of the plywood. This area is about 12 inches from plywood to ground. At this time it's just exposed dirt, but I plan to spray bottom with bleach mix and put down back plastic in the next few months.
I realize now I should have put down gravel or plastic, but I did not because the ground does not have a water issue in this area. That was my mistake. Ground still feels moist after winter. The white mold seems to be heaviest around the open ends.
Besides putting down plastic and killing the existing mold, do i need to paint the bottom of the shed plywood? I would have to jack the whole 12x12 shed up to get under it to paint, and may have to even just to spray the bleach to kill the mold.
I read that this white mold does not eat the wood. Do I really need to worry about painting it or just put down plastic and live with any white mold that forms? It seems to wipe off with just water
Thanks for your time
Dean

Comment: Did you use plywood rated for outdoor use? In general, until/unless the wood starts showing significant signs of rot, I'd say ignore it. Nature colonizes any available micro-biome...

Comment: keshlam - I just used CDX plywood. I wish I would have used marine plywood now. I figured since it would not be exposed to "water" that it would not be an issue.